# what is best practice for authorize and authenticate a worker service in IdentityServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I have a service provider (`SP`) that is secured by `Duende IdentityServer` (`IdP`) and I can authorize and authenticate my users and check their access level permissions by using claims.

now I have a new worker service that should connect to my `SP` and perform some actions by calling some APIs. I also need the identifier to determine the invoker of the web service. Also, I need to ensure that the worker can only access permitted APIs and other actions cannot be invoked by this worker service.

I know there is a client secret mechanism to secure API against unauthorized workers but I need permission and something like subId to identify the invoker.

what is the best practice and recommended authentication flow for this scenario? I searched a lot but I did not find a good sample for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For service-to-service communication when there is no user involved, then you should use the **client credentials flow**.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/quickstarts/1_client_credentials/) and [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/overview/terminology/#machine-to-machine-communication) in the documentation

Comment: But I need the modifier userId or client Id to determine the modifier entities and is there any way to limit this client access to only a part of all APIs.

Comment: client credentials flow is all about securing services-to-service communication, but then you can in your application logic, add a UserID claim in the provided request between servicesw and via authorization determine if the user is allowed to do some specific action or not.